# In the following Swift code why does the program exit while loop when it reaches break?

Tags: swift, for-loop, while-loop, break

In the following Swift code why does the program exit while loop when it reaches break? Shouldn't it only exit the if and not the while loop.

```
var cokeLeft = 7
var fantasLeft = 4

while (cokeLeft > 0) {

    println("You have \(cokeLeft) Cokes left.")
    cokeLeft = cokeLeft - 1

    if(cokeLeft <= fantasLeft){
        break
    }
}
println("You stop drinking Cokes.")
```

Comment: Where is the for loop?

Comment: @Dko Sorry I meant to say if

Comment: breaks generally exit out of the nearest loop. while is a loop. if is not considered to be a  loop.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaks generally exit out of the nearest loop. while is a loop. if is not considered to be a loop. Here is the corresponding documentation.

[From the IOS Developer Library:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID441)

> A break statement ends program execution of a loop or a switch
>   statement.

Also, [from the IOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html):

> Loop statements allow a block of code to be executed repeatedly,
>   depending on the conditions specified in the loop. Swift has four loop
>   statements: a for statement, a for-in statement, a while statement,
>   and a do-while statement.

So, here you can see that "if" is not listed among the loop statements.

Comment: Incidentally, `break` works in exactly the same way in C/Objective-C.